# Custom static cast function template in C++14

Tags: c++, templates, casting, c++14, return-value-optimization

I've written such a template function for static casting as kind of an exercise:

```
template<typename cT, typename T>
inline constexpr cT sCast(T carg) {
    return static_cast<cT>(carg);
}
```

I just didn't want to type `static_cast<someT>(some_obj)` all the time, so I challenged myself to write my own template function with a shorter name. However, I knew I can do something much easier in one line of code:

```
#define sCast static_cast
   ...
sCast<someT>(some_obj);
```

But as I said, I wanted to design a function template just for exercise.

Now my question is: is this function template as efficient as possible and if not, how can it be better? Will template functions meet conditions of RVO optimalization? Or maybe I'm just a perfectionist and such ideas are waste of time?

Comment: Functions, and especially macros, like that tend to make code harder to read, understand and maintain. It might be a good exercise, but please don't use it more than that.

Comment: The `static_cast` keyword is chosen to be ugly on purpose, so it stands out in the code, and so that you should *really* think twice before using it. Hiding it in a macro is definitely not the solution to the ugliness. Not using it much is.

Comment: How about C-style casts? If you're not casting to pointers/references, they're as safe at `static_cast`, and also the syntax is as short as theoretically possible.

Comment: Not wanting to type something very standard is the wrong approach. Just type standard C++ and anybody can understand your code. Regardless you should be careful with static_cast anyway. Can you explain to us where you use want to use static_cast and why?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Hahaha that made my day. Doubt OP will get it though.

Comment: @PepijnKramer I don't think I get it either. :) What do you mean?

Comment: Well if you want "UB" then C-style casts are an even faster way to get there. (So I assumed some cynicism there) ;) (But then again, I half missed your pointers comment)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Nah, I'm being serious. I even think that banning them unconditionally (when the target type is not a pointer/reference) is a form of a cargo cult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this template is not as efficient as just using `static_cast`. The reason is that the function has to be explicitly pushed onto the stack, and its arguments have to be cleaned up afterwards. Most compilers will inline it (==> it is as if you wrote `static_cast` instead of the function from above), but if your compiler chooses to not inline it, it will impact your performance (even though just slightly, and its unlikely anyone would ever notice that)

Answer (score 0):

Your template is not a replacement for `static_cast` at all.

Consider the case where references are involved. Without specifying the second parameter explicitly, you'll end up without references being deduced:

```
struct Test
{
    Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test::Test()\n";
    }

    Test(Test&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test::Test(Test&&)\n";
    }

    Test(Test const&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test::Test(Test const&)\n";
    }

    Test& operator=(Test&&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test::operator=(Test&&)\n";
        return *this;
    }

    Test& operator=(Test const&)
    {
        std::cout << "Test::operator=(Test const&)\n";
        return *this;
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test::~Test()\n";
    }
};

template<typename cT, typename T>
inline constexpr cT sCast(T carg) {
    return static_cast<cT>(carg);
}

int main()
{
    Test original;
    std::cout << "before static_cast\n";
    Test const& withStaticCast = static_cast<Test const&>(original);
    std::cout << "before sCast\n";
    Test const& withScast = sCast<Test const&>(original);
    std::cout << "after sCast\n";

    std::cout << std::boolalpha
        << (&original == &withStaticCast) << '\n'
        << (&original == &withScast) << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Test::Test()
before static_cast
before sCast
Test::Test(Test const&)
Test::~Test()
after sCast
true
false
Test::~Test()
```

As you can see there's an extra copy being made by `sCast` and this copy is even destroyed before the next expression which could easily result in undefined behaviour.

Using forwarding references you could fix this problem, but you'd still end up with different semantics in some cases:

```
template<typename cT, typename T>
constexpr cT sCast(T&& carg)
{
    return static_cast<cT>(std::forward<T>(carg));
}
```

Code where this has different semantics:

```
std::cout << "before static_cast\n";
Test withStaticCast = static_cast<Test>(Test());
std::cout << "before sCast\n";
Test withScast = sCast<Test>(Test{});
std::cout << "after sCast\n";
```

Output

```
before static_cast
Test::Test()
before sCast
Test::Test()
Test::Test(Test&&)
Test::~Test()
after sCast
```

---

My recommendation is to keep using `static_cast`. This will also help other people reading your code; they are almost certainly familiar with `static_cast`, but it's likely they'll need to look up `sCast`, at least the first time they encounter that function. Also IDEs will highlight `static_cast` differently than function template calls.

In general I don't consider it a good idea to shorten the code at all cost. If by typing a few more chars you add readability, it's worth the effort. If you cannot be bothered with the typing, there's still search&replace functionality available in pretty much every text editor...

Answer (score 0):

In C++14: casting to a non-reference type will create a copy. That copy is subject to RVO, but static_cast will just never have that extra temporary to copy/move from. For example:

```cpp
struct X { operator std::string(); operator std::mutex(); };

// Same as `X{}.operator std::string();`
static_cast<std::string>(X{});

// Same as `std::string(X{}.operator std::string())`: May move, may be elided
sCast<std::string>(X{});

static_cast<std::mutex>(X{});  // Same as `X{}.operator std::mutex();`
//sCast<std::mutex>(X{});  // Does not compile: mutex not movable
```

This problem does not exist in C++17 since the elision of that move is mandatory.

---

There is also special wording for `static_cast`. Lifetime extension can be done through static casts and they are not type-dependent if the type casted to isn't.

```
const X& x = static_cast<const X&>(X{});  // This will extend the lifetime of the temporary
const X& y = sCast<const X&>(X{});  // This will be a dangling reference

struct TempFn { template<typename> void f(); };
template<typename T>
void g(T t) {
    // OK: static_cast<TempFn>(t) is not type-dependent
    static_cast<TempFn>(t).f<int>();
    // Error: sCast<TempFn>(t) is type-dependent
    //sCast<TempFn>(t).f<int>();
    sCast<TempFn>(t).template f<int>();
}
```

This cannot be emulated with a function template.

---

Your function also doesn't handle rvalues properly and always copies it's arguments. E.g.:

```cpp
struct Y : X { operator int() &&; };

static_cast<int>(Y{});  // Works
sCast<int>(Y{});  // Tries to cast lvalue `carg` to int. Does not work.

Y y;
static_cast<X&>(y);  // Works: reference to base of y
sCast<X&>(y);  // Dangling reference to base of temporary
```

This can be fixed with perfect forwarding:

```cpp
template<typename cT, typename T>
inline constexpr cT sCast(T&& carg) {
    return static_cast<cT>(std::forward<T>(carg));
}
```

---

Your function isn't SFINAE friendly. During overload resolution, it will claim to always be callable. For example:

```cpp
template<typename Integral>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<Integral>> f(Integral x);

template<typename Stringy>
decltype(void(sCast<std::string>(std::declval<Stringy>()))) f(Stringy&& s) {
    std::string str = sCast<std::string>(std::forward<Stringy>(s));
    return f(parseint(str));
}

// sCast<std::string>(std::declval<Stringy>()) isn't a substitution failure
// even if Stringy is `int`
```

You can fix this by making it a substitution failure when the `static_cast` would fail. Easiest is like this:

```cpp
template<typename cT, typename T>
inline constexpr decltype(static_cast<cT>(std::declval<T>())) sCast(T&& carg) {
    return static_cast<cT>(std::forward<T>(carg));
}
```

---

Your function template cannot take prvalues properly. The "perfect forwarding" above changes prvalues into xvalues. For example:

```cpp
// The same as `X{}`.
static_cast<X>(X{});

// Cannot be elided. Required to move from a temporary, and for `X` to be move constructible.
// Possibly moves from two temporaries as described in the first point in C++14
sCast<X>(X{});

// C++23
// operator int() can only be called on a prvalue
struct Z { Z() = default; Z(Z&&) = delete; operator int(this Z); };
static_cast<int>(Z{});  // Works
sCast<int>(Z{});  // Tries to call operator int on an xvalue. Cannot move into object parameter.
```